# Dojo Toolkit 1.8.3 Mobile dojo/on Handler Event Switch Widget

Tags: javascript, html, events, mobile, dojo

I am trying to create a basic event handler for a dojox.mobile.Switch widget using the onStateChanged event. I am using dojo/on event handler module with respect to the new AMD architecture and having a hard time to get it to listen to my switch event.

**Here is the HTML for the switch widget with id=mobileView**

```
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'../../app/images/i-      icon-1.png'">
      Mobile Version
    <div id="mobileView" class="mblItemSwitch" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Switch"></div>
    </li>
```

**Here is the JS code code. The second require is suppose to handle the switch event.**

```
    require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme","dojox/mobile/compat", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(parser) {
    parser.parse();
    });

    require(["dojo/on", "dijit/dijit"], 
    function(on){
    on(dijit.byId("mobileView"), 
    "onStateChanged", 
    function(newState){
    alert(newState);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I can see that it is binding itself to the widget using dijit.byId, listening for the event onStateChanged, and calling the preceding function once the state changes. I am thinking it has something to do with having the correct modules included in the require, however I am not really sure. I have spent hours on this and have tried many different methods including the old way of dojo.connect.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

[Reference: dojo/on Dojo Toolkit dojo/on](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of dojo, `dojo.connect()` handled both DOM events (click, focus, etc) and function calls on a widget.

However, the newer `dojo/on` module handles DOM events, and the `dojo/aspect` module handles function calls. Switch.onStateChanged() is a function, not a DOM event, so you want something like this:

```
require(["dojo/aspect", "dijit/registry"], function(aspect, registry) {
     aspect.after(registry.byId("mobileView"), "onStateChanged", 
       function(newState){
         alert(newState);
       }
     );
});
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/connect.html for more info.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you for the quick response, code snippet, and reference link! This is working just as I wanted it to!